# android change background color of 1 item in listview

Tags: listview, android-listview

i try to change a background of selected item in listview and i got more item get selected when i scroll the listview.
i know it happend because i recycle my item list but i couldn't find how to solve this issue

here my code:
    class BabyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
    BabyHolder babyholder;

    BabyAdapter(ArrayList<BabyHolder> list) {
        super(BabyNames.this, R.layout.namerow, R.id.tvName, list);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.getTag();

        if(tv == null){
            tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            row.setTag(tv);
        }

        row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

            }
        });

        babyholder = getItem(position);
        tv.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
        tv.setText(babyholder.name);

        return row;
    }
}

public BabyHolder getItem(int position) {
    return (((BabyAdapter) getListAdapter()).getItem(position));
}
```

thanks for the help :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go to the layout.xml file that is used to inflate the listView and in that set the background to something like this :

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```